# Can PowerShell be an ActiveScriptEventConsumer?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, event-handling, wmi-query

I need to continuously watch a particular "drop" folder for (tiny) pdfs and auto-print and delete them.  The printing itself is being handled by SumatraPDF (because I don't think there is a built-in, Windows method).

Creating a temporary WMI event monitor in PowerShell is pretty straightforward:

```sh
$WQLquery = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 " +
            "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' " +
            "AND TargetInstance.Extension = 'pdf' " +
            "AND TargetInstance.Drive = '$($Drive):' " +
            "AND TargetInstance.Path = '$($Folder.replace('\','\\'))'"

$Action = {
   $TimedOut = $null
   $PrintProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $Sumatra -ArgumentList "-Print-To $Printer `"$($EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name)`""  -PassThru
   $PrintProcess | Wait-Process -Timeout 10 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable TimedOut
   if ($TimedOut) {
      "Printing $($EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name) timed out." | Out-File $ErrorLogPath -Append
      $PrintProcess.kill
   } elseif ($PrintProcess.ExitCode -ne 0) {
      "Error for $($EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name) : $($PrintProcess.ExitCode)" | Out-File $ErrorLogPath -Append
   } else {
      Remove-Item $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name -Force
   }
}

Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query $wqlquery -SourceIdentifier 'FileCreated' -Action $Action
```

When it comes to creating a permanent event subscription, I can replace the `Action` and `Register-CimIndicationEvent` with:

```sh
# This creates a permanent event monitor that lasts through a reboot
# Step One:  Create a Filter object
$FilterArgs = @{
   ClassName    = '__EventFilter'
   NameSpace    = 'root\subscription'
   Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
   ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
   Property     = @{
      Name           = 'PDFCreatedFilter'
      EventNamespace = 'root\CIMV2'
      QueryLanguage  = 'WQL'
      Query          = $WQLQuery
   }
}
$FilterInstance = New-CimInstance @FilterArgs

# Step Two:  Create a Consumer object
$ConsumerArgs = @{
   ClassName    = 'ActiveScriptEventConsumer'
   NameSpace    = 'root\subscription'
   Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
   ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
   Property     = @{
      Name           = 'FileCreatedConsumer'
      EventNamespace = 'root\CIMV2'
      ScriptingEngine = ''   # <---- What goes here for PowerShell?
      ScriptFileName  = ''   # <---- What goes here for PowerShell?
   }
}

$ConsumerInstance = New-CimInstance @ConsumerArgs

# Step Three:  Create a Binding object between the Filter and Consumer
$BindingArgs = @{
   ClassName    = '__FilterToConsumerBinding'
   NameSpace    = 'root\subscription'
   Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
   ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
   Property     = @{
      Filter   = [Ref]$FilterArgs
      Consumer = [Ref]$ConsumerArgs
   }
}
$BindingInstance = New-CimInstance @BindingArgs
```

However, and you can see, I am unsure about the `ActiveScriptEventConsumer`.  [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/activescripteventconsumer) says it can be "in an arbitrary scripting language", but every example I can find uses VBScript only.  I'd really like to use PowerShell.

Is PowerShell a valid `Scripting Engine`?

If yes, can someone provide the syntax for the `ScriptingEngine` and `ScriptText` properties to get it to work?

If no, am I better off hacking together some noob VBScript (yuck!) or using an `CommandLineEventConsumer` to start a PowerShell script (that I then have to watch/protect)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking if Powershell is an Active Scripting language, the answer is no.

Comment: I suppose that answers my primary question.  I wish MS would make it more clear what constitutes a valid "arbitrary scripting language"!  Thanks though.  I guess I'll be diving into VBscript again <shudder> because that seems safer than relying on an external script.

Comment: The main reason will be that [Active Scripting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting) is an old technology now and finding any official information is next to impossible because it’s been superseded by technologies like Powershell.

Comment: looking at the `CommandLineEventConsumer` [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/commandlineeventconsumer#remarks) it looks like you could in theory minimize the `$Action` scriptblock and do something to the tune of `$ConsumerArgs.Property.CommandLineTemplate = "PowerShell.exe -command '$($Action.ToString())'"`; however you're still going to have to worry about locking down the `$Sumatra` executable.